# Many-to-many holding information about a relationship

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm, doctrine, domain-driven-design

In an ORM (no preference), how to best represent a many-to-many relationship between two models, when we need to hold information about this relationship?

```
I have an Order, which can have many Products.
A Product can belong to many Orders.
```

An Order can have several pieces of information attached to each Product: quantity, special request, ...

In database design, this is represented by a junction table, which holds the `quantity` and `specialRequest` fields.

But how to correctly represent this in an ORM, where I would just like to use `order.products` and get a collection of `Products`? As I plan to use an *Identity Map*, there must be only one instance of a same Product across all orders, which prevents me from having some kind of "modified" Product which would contain the extra information.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate many-to-many mapping - additional column in the mapping table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889513/nhibernate-many-to-many-mapping-additional-column-in-the-mapping-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According Eric Evans's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), many-to-many associations often introduce a lot of complexity into domain and recommended approach is to decrease count of such associations in your domain. In your particular case Order is an aggregate root, which contains bunch of OrderItems that hold quantity and specialRequest fields.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Vadim above.  The easiest way to accomplish this is to add an intermediate entity (OrderItem) that represents this relationship with the additional columns.  I don't think you want to treat this as a many to many between orders and products.